# Spark SQL query to get the last updated timestamp of a Athena table stored as CSV in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-athena

Is it possible to get the last updated timestamp of a Athena Table stored as a CSV file format in S3 location using Spark SQL query.

If yes, can someone please provide more information on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. Use the athena jdbc driver and do a spark read where the format is jdbc. In this read you will provide your "select max(timestamp) from table" query. Then as the next step just save to s3 fcrom the spark dataframe
2. You can skip the jdbc read altogther and just use boto3 to run the above query. It would be a combination of start_query_execution and get_query_results. You can then save this to s3 as well.